# Unable to use ElementMarker in DirichletCondition with structured quad mesh

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh, boundary-conditions

I would like to use `ElementMarker` in a `DirichletCondition` on a structured quad mesh, but I am receiving the error:

`NDSolveValue::bcnop: No places were found on the boundary where ElementMarker==2 was True, so DirichletCondition[u==1,ElementMarker==2] will effectively be ignored.`

Here is an example of a small mesh where `ElementMarker==2` appears to be on the bottom boundary.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bounds = <|"inlet" -> 1, "hot" -> 2, "outlet" -> 3|>;
regs = <|"solid" -> 10, "fluid" -> 20, "interface" -> 15|>;
crd = {{0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.4002986944615309`}, {0.`, 
    0.8326451978805829`}, {0.`, 1.2996052494743657`}, {0.`, 
    1.803950000871885`}, {0.`, 2.348672461377994`}, {0.`, 
    2.9370052598409973`}, {0.`, 3.5724398285307286`}, {0.`, 
    4.258747122872904`}, {0.`, 5.`}, {1.`, 0.`}, {1.`, 
    0.4002986944615309`}, {1.`, 0.8326451978805829`}, {1.`, 
    1.2996052494743657`}, {1.`, 1.803950000871885`}, {1.`, 
    2.348672461377994`}, {1.`, 2.9370052598409973`}, {1.`, 
    3.5724398285307286`}, {1.`, 4.258747122872904`}, {1.`, 5.`}, {2.`,
     0.`}, {2.`, 0.4002986944615309`}, {2.`, 
    0.8326451978805829`}, {2.`, 1.2996052494743657`}, {2.`, 
    1.803950000871885`}, {2.`, 2.348672461377994`}, {2.`, 
    2.9370052598409973`}, {2.`, 3.5724398285307286`}, {2.`, 
    4.258747122872904`}, {2.`, 5.`}, {3.`, 0.`}, {3.`, 
    0.4002986944615309`}, {3.`, 0.8326451978805829`}, {3.`, 
    1.2996052494743657`}, {3.`, 1.803950000871885`}, {3.`, 
    2.348672461377994`}, {3.`, 2.9370052598409973`}, {3.`, 
    3.5724398285307286`}, {3.`, 4.258747122872904`}, {3.`, 5.`}, {4.`,
     0.`}, {4.`, 0.4002986944615309`}, {4.`, 
    0.8326451978805829`}, {4.`, 1.2996052494743657`}, {4.`, 
    1.803950000871885`}, {4.`, 2.348672461377994`}, {4.`, 
    2.9370052598409973`}, {4.`, 3.5724398285307286`}, {4.`, 
    4.258747122872904`}, {4.`, 5.`}, {5.`, 0.`}, {5.`, 
    0.4002986944615309`}, {5.`, 0.8326451978805829`}, {5.`, 
    1.2996052494743657`}, {5.`, 1.803950000871885`}, {5.`, 
    2.348672461377994`}, {5.`, 2.9370052598409973`}, {5.`, 
    3.5724398285307286`}, {5.`, 4.258747122872904`}, {5.`, 5.`}};
melms = {QuadElement[{{1, 11, 12, 2}, {2, 12, 13, 3}, {3, 13, 14, 
      4}, {4, 14, 15, 5}, {5, 15, 16, 6}, {6, 16, 17, 7}, {7, 17, 18, 
      8}, {8, 18, 19, 9}, {9, 19, 20, 10}, {11, 21, 22, 12}, {12, 22, 
      23, 13}, {13, 23, 24, 14}, {14, 24, 25, 15}, {15, 25, 26, 
      16}, {16, 26, 27, 17}, {17, 27, 28, 18}, {18, 28, 29, 19}, {19, 
      29, 30, 20}, {21, 31, 32, 22}, {22, 32, 33, 23}, {23, 33, 34, 
      24}, {24, 34, 35, 25}, {25, 35, 36, 26}, {26, 36, 37, 27}, {27, 
      37, 38, 28}, {28, 38, 39, 29}, {29, 39, 40, 30}, {31, 41, 42, 
      32}, {32, 42, 43, 33}, {33, 43, 44, 34}, {34, 44, 45, 35}, {35, 
      45, 46, 36}, {36, 46, 47, 37}, {37, 47, 48, 38}, {38, 48, 49, 
      39}, {39, 49, 50, 40}, {41, 51, 52, 42}, {42, 52, 53, 43}, {43, 
      53, 54, 44}, {44, 54, 55, 45}, {45, 55, 56, 46}, {46, 56, 57, 
      47}, {47, 57, 58, 48}, {48, 58, 59, 49}, {49, 59, 60, 50}}, {10,
      10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
     10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
     10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}]};
bcEle = {LineElement[{{1, 11}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}, {6, 
      5}, {7, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 8}, {20, 10}, {10, 9}, {11, 21}, {30, 
      20}, {21, 31}, {40, 30}, {31, 41}, {50, 40}, {41, 51}, {51, 
      52}, {52, 53}, {53, 54}, {54, 55}, {55, 56}, {56, 57}, {57, 
      58}, {58, 59}, {59, 60}, {60, 50}}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
     0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]};
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, "MeshElements" -> melms, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> bcEle];
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue, 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {Black, Green, Red}, ImageSize -> Medium]]
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Red]}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

[image: Mesh]

If I apply a modified version of the heat equation taken from [Solving PDEs with FEM Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1222366601) to the mesh, then `NDSovleValue` says it can't find the `Marker`:

```
op = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, x, y]\)\) - \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(u[t, x, y]\)\);
dc = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, 
   ElementMarker == bounds["hot"]];
ufunHeat = 
  NDSolveValue[{op == 0, dc, u[0, x, y] == 0}, 
   u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
frames = Table[
   Plot3D[ufunHeat[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {t, 0, 5, 0.5}];
ListAnimate[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

If I remove the `ElementMarker` condition from the `DirichletCondition` and replace it with a coordinate condition like so

```
dc = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, y == 0];
```

Then `NDSolve` appears to work normally.

I have used this `ElementMarker` construct on triangular meshes without issue.  Should this construct also work with quads?  Do I need to specify the marker differently to get `NDSolve` to recognize it?

Comment: DirchletCondtions use the markers from PointElements not  from MeshElements nor from BoundaryElements. If you can not figure it out by tomorrow I'll write an example. IIRC there is one in the ElementMesh generation tutorial.

Comment: In your example you'd need to add `PointElement` for the dirichlet condition.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will try to find that section.  That makes sense since the DC is a nodal condition.  Perhaps, just union the element incidents of the BoundaryElements?   Ultimately, I would like to be able to use the approach to process other meshes.  It is much easier for me to detect boundaries by region ID and normals.

Comment: Ideally yes, but what should be done a node 2 in this case `LineElement[{{1,2},{2,3}},{1,2}]`? Any preference?

Comment: Do you mean cases where a node is shared by two boundaries?  That is a good question.  `PointElement[Transpose@{{1, 2, 1}}, {1, 2, 3}]` allows me to assign multiple markers to node 1, but will `ToElementMesh` or `NDSolve` allow it or do I need determine a precedence hierarchy for the nodal BC's?  These are good questions that I will need to experiment with.

Comment: I looked at some old triangle meshes made with bmesh following the tutorial and there are no duplicate PointElements, so I will take that to mean they should be unique.  So, a boundary destined for a DC should get the nodes.  An inconsistency will occur when you have 2 DCs on adjacent surfaces and you will need to make a choice and you may see an artifact in the corner.  To avoid the artifacts, you probably need to extend the model with insulated regions to avoid 2 adjacent DCs. I was probably taught that at some point but forgot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. It is important to realize that `DirichletConditions` use the markers present in `PointElements` not the ones in the `MeshElements` nor the ones in the `BoundaryElements`. The markers in the `BoundaryElements` are used exclusively for `NeumannVaues` and the markers in `MeshElements` are exlusively used for PDE coefficients that use markers. This is documented in the [ElementMesh Generation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#2047054515) tutorial.

We start by extracting the `PointElements` from the mesh you have:

```
 mesh["PointElements"]
{PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, \
{10}, {11}, {20}, {21}, {30}, {31}, {40}, {41}, {50}, {51}, {52}, \
{53}, {54}, {55}, {56}, {57}, {58}, {59}, {60}}]}

mesh[
 "Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
  "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Black, ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

[image]

Now we add markers to the `PointElements`

```
pMarkers = {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 99, 0, 99, 0, 99, 0, 99, 0, 
99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

pEle = {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, \
{10}, {11}, {20}, {21}, {30}, {31}, {40}, {41}, {50}, {51}, {52}, \
{53}, {54}, {55}, {56}, {57}, {58}, {59}, {60}},
pMarkers]};
```

Recreate the mesh:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, "MeshElements" -> melms, 
"BoundaryElements" -> bcEle, "PointElements" -> pEle];
```

We look at the point element markers. Note that the numbering can be completely different from that in the, say, boundary elements.

```
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
  "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue, 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {Black, Green, Red}, ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

[image]

A different approach is to use the `BoundaryMarkerFunction` and the `PointMarkerFunction` documented in the options section of `ToBoundaryMesh`.

The reason that the point element markers are not populated automatically is the following: Imagine you have a line segment `LineElement[{{1,2},{2,3}},{1,2}]` which marker should be attributed to the node with index 2? In general markers are a single positive integer for for a point/line/mesh element. So assigning two marker to a single element is currently not an option. If someone has other ideas please let me know. Have a look at the `PointMarkerFunction` that could be used.

Comment: +1   @user21 I didn't know about all information regarding markers in the first paragraph? Is this documented? I think it should be.

Comment: @Pinti, sure, I added a link to the relevant section.

Comment: @user21 Thank you very much for your detailed answer.  I makes much sense and was documented, but I did not make the connection.  One question I have is there a logic to how the automatic triangle mesh generation creates `PointMarkers` or is it arbitrary?  One FEM tool I use, has a precedence setting that allows a shared PointElement at the intersection of  multiple boundaries to take on the highest rank precedence. There is always a good chance that you chose poorly so you can change the precedence without redoing the mesh.

Comment: @TimLaska, interesting: how is this rank precedence defined? For the `PointMarkers` in triangle meshes, I'd need to look that up. I'll get back to you with that. (need to finish something else first)

Comment: @TimLaska, so this is done during the call of `TriangleLink` that provides the actual triangulation. I think this has the same issues we discussed and makes a random choice of point element marker at nodes where it's clear which marker they should belong to.

Comment: @user21 I will send you some screen caps once I get the license manager up if that is okay?