# Numerically solve for the potential of a point charge in a periodic cubic domain

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

How can I obtain the 3D numerical solution for the potential (or field) due to a point charge inside a cubic domain with periodic boundary conditions in all directions? I guess I can use `NDSolveValue` with first argument:

```
-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == diracD
```

to represent Gauss' Law $\nabla^2 \phi(r)=-q\delta(r)/\epsilon_0$. The function `diracD` approximates a Dirac delta function, e.g.: $diracD(x,y,z,\epsilon)=(\epsilon/ \pi)/(x^2 + y^2+z^2 + \epsilon^2)$ with some small value for $\epsilon$. I probably need to also make use of `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`.

Comment: You can't really use DiracDelta in numerical computation. It works only with `DSolve`. This is an analytical entity and has no meaning for numerical work. Math people call it a distribution. You need to approximate it with a real function that NDSolve can understand. Like a very large spike at some location with a very area it sits on or something like this.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, I replaced it with a numerical approximation to a Dirac delta.

Comment: For this simple case, you can solve it symbolically with DSolve[Laplacian[u[r], {r, th, phi}] == k DiracDelta[r], u, {r}], then plug numbers in to the solution: {{u -> Function[{r}, C[1] + r C[2] + k r HeavisideTheta[r]]}}. Is there a reason you want to do this numerically?

Comment: @jdp Thanks but I want to solve it numerically because I will use this as a starting point for more complicated cases. The solution also needs to be periodic.

Comment: Okay. I found an example in the documentation which is close to what you want, except for the delta function. ref/PeriodicBoundaryCondition under Scope/3D Problems shows how to set up a Laplacian in a cube, using Cartesian coordinates. For the delta function, try n*HeavisidePi[x/n], where n is some suitable constant. The x/n determines the width, and multiplying by n fixes the normalization,which should be unity.

Comment: 1D analogue of this problem was discussed here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209169/solve-a-one-dimensional-heat-transfer-problem-with-ndsolve/210124#210124 May be it can help you

Comment: I'm missing the definition of the periodic domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @jdp's helpful hint, try:

```
eps = .01
dirac = Function[x, Exp[-(x^2/(2 eps))]/Sqrt[2 Pi eps]]

cube=Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]
```

Examplary solution for `DiracDelta` at `x=y=z=1/2`

```
U  = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
dirac[x - 1/2] dirac[y - 1/2] dirac[z - 1/2], 
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y, z], x == 1, 
TranslationTransform[{-1, 0, 0}]],
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y, z], x == 0, 
TranslationTransform[{ 1, 0, 0}]],
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y, z], y == 1, 
TranslationTransform[{0, -1 , 0}]],
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y, z], y == 0, 
TranslationTransform[{ 0, 1, 0}]],
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y, z], z == 1, 
TranslationTransform[{0, 0, -1}]],
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y, z], z == 0, 
TranslationTransform[{ 0, 0, 1}]]}
, u, {x, y, z} \[Element] cube]

SliceContourPlot3D[U[x, y, z], 
{{"XStackedPlanes", {0.25, 0.5, .75}}, {"YStackedPlanes",1}, {"ZStackedPlanes", 1}}, {x, y, z} \[Element] cube, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, it seems correct but did you mean to use `cube` instead of `\[CapitalOmega]` ? As you've written it above it doesn't execute without errors.

Comment: @kotozna You are right, thanks for your hint, I modified my answer